# strcmp comparing incorrectly

Tags: c++, strcmp

So I was running this code to open a file and compare a local char to the values stored in the file, but for some weird reason, strcmp is telling me that "15" is equal to "17".. any thoughts? It's strange because the problem only happens at the 17th line.. Here's the relevant code:

```
...
string line;
size_t found;
size_t nextFound;
char ID[11]; 
char storage_ID[11] = "15";


//Open the file
ifstream file(FILE);
if (file.is_open()) 
{
     for (int count = 0; count < 25; count++) 
     {
         getline(file,line);  
         if (file.eof()) 
         {
             return;
         }
         //store object ID
         found = line.find(":");
         strcpy(ID[count],line.substr(0,found).c_str()); //stores ID from the start of a line until a ":" is found
         if(strcmp(storage_ID,ID[count])==0) 
         {
            foundID = true;
         }

         else
         {
             foundID = false;
         }
```

And here's what the file looks like:

```
...
1:1234567890:101:A123B4CD
2:2234567890:102:B123B4CD
3:3234567890:103:C123B4CD
(this goes on for 20 lines)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code, as you compare a string with a single character. Same with the `strcpy` call in the line above.

Comment: You also `strcpy` into a `char`. Is `ID` supposed to be an array of strings?

Comment: Also, why are you using C-style strings in a C++ program, where you already are using the C++ `std::string` class for some variables?

Comment: Why are you using `strcmp` with C++ strings? Just use the == operator, it supports C strings too. Actually, why are you using C strings at all?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: That's not just undefined behavior. `strcmp` requires two `char*` arguments; the second argument being passed, `ID[count]` is of type `char`. That shouldn't even compile -- and any conforming compiler must at least warn about it.

Comment: Wow- first I forgot to mention that ID is a 2D array (char ID[16][11]), which can explain the _undefined behavior_ at line 17. strcmp is working just fine- this one is on me guys! Thanks for the catch!

Comment: You "forgot to mention" that `ID` is a 2D array? The code you posted has `char ID[11];`. *Always* copy-and-paste the code you're actually compiling: http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something wrong in the code, you are declaring `char ID[11];` an array of 11 chars, in the loop where *count* go from 0 to 25 your assigning to ID[count] (when count is 12, you are reading the 12 ID from the file, you will be writing to invalid memory ID[12-?])

The code should be:

```
char ID[11];
...
strcpy(ID,line.substr(0,found).c_str()); //stores ID from the start of a line until a ":" is found
```

Assuming no ID has size > 11

Comment: Thanks @NetVipeC - I inputted the wrong information about the ID array, but you nailed the point. Thanks!